# Passing variables from normal function to init_UI function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have been facing a problem in using a variable of a normal class function and `initUI` function.
The code looks like this:

```
def text_trans(self):
    ...
    number = 2
    ...
def init_UI(self):
    number = text_transfer(self)
    print(number)
    QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self,"generated","generated")
```

I wrote the above code but it shows a name error. Is there a way, I can use the number variable in the first function in the second one?

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote the above code but it shows a name error.

Probably because, for starters, `text_transfer != text_trans` and, secondly, in the body of methods you should use `self` to access other methods. So, `init_UI` should look like:

```
def init_UI(self):
    number = self.text_trans()
    print(number)
```

You access the name through `self`, and `self` is then implicitly passed to the invoked function, so `text_transfer(self)` won't work.

> Is there a way, I can use the number variable in the first function in the second one?

In most cases, this is done by simply *returning* the wanted name from a given function:

```
def text_trans(self):
    ...
    number = 2
    return number
```